# Facing problem while running the code for dual recording in twilio with java

Tags: java, twilio-api

I am trying to crate recording from twilio dual channel recording but I am getting an error as

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with
>   path [/control-api-explorer] threw exception [Request processing
>   failed; nested exception is com.twilio.exception.ApiException:
>   Requested resource is not eligible for recording] with root cause
>
> I tried to debug the code and got the error  Error - 21220 Invalid
>   call state You attempted a realtime operation on a Call that was not
>   in-progress. Calls that have completed cannot be recorded or
>   redirected.

```
Twilio.init(account,auth);
              System.out.println("Recording....");
              Recording recording = Recording.creator(callSid)
              .setRecordingStatusCallback(URI.create("https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/"+account+"/Calls/"+callSid+"/Recordings.json"))
    .setRecordingStatusCallbackEvent(Promoter.listOfOne(CALL_STATUS_CALLBACK_EVENTS.get(0).toString()))
        .setRecordingChannels("dual").create();
             System.out.println("Recording Completed....");
```

help in providing a solution to get live recording using dual channel without dial verb of twiml.

Answer (score 2):

I also had a problem with recording and  even though I checked that the call was in-progress, I still got the error 21220.

I was able to fix the error and record phone calls by adding a timeout of 3 seconds.

`setTimeout(function () {twilio_phone.recordPhoneCall (CallSid); }, 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to check if the callSid has joined a conference.  Twilio has API call for front end and back end to get a participant list for a on going conference.  If the call has joined a conference successfully, if would be ready to have the recording turned on.